I need words that sounds like Червоний, Жовтий or Зелений for a magic show
I will perform magic shows for Ukranian kids. I am using silks in one routine (red, yellow and green). Since I don't speak ukranian I want to mispronounce the colors so the kids have a laugh. For exemple in English, instead of saying "red", I would say "bread".
Is there any words close in their pronouciation to Червоний, Жовтий and Зелений?

червоний -> черговий

I've remembered and can offer such variants.

червоний — черговий (next, on duty), чирвовий (of Hearts), чреватий (fraught), череватий (potbellied);
зелений — займенний (pronouny), желейний (jelly), земельний (agrarian, land), зловмисний (malicious);
жовтий — жовчний (gall), жирний (fat), жонатий (married), зжатий (reaped).


Creating variants for playful mispronunciations in a different language, especially without speaking it fluently, can be challenging.
I would advise asking this question to ChatGPT or Claude and roll options in search for the most suitable one.
Here are some variants:
Жовтий (yellow)
Pronounce it like "zholud-tiy" to make it sound like the word for acorn - "zholud"
Зелений (Green)
Consider "Земля" (Zemlya), meaning "earth" or "ground". This doesn't match phonetically but sticking with the 'Ze-' start could work in a playful context.

If it's humorous, then it may make (though doesn't necessarily makes) sense to make words rhyme (even at the price of objective similarity).
What I've found:

черво́ний — соло́ний (salty)
зеле́ний — пале́ний (burned and also, in slang, counterfeitly produced), шале́ний (crazy)
жо́втий — sorry, no idea here ☹

